# Anchor menu # without Path system URL

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, weblinks

I have bought a template, this template has an HTML5 template like , i mean the different sections are separarted as sections and its menus click make an slides to them, but , i don't know why, the system lynks , with external URL options is adding the path to the #anchorlinktodesiredsection
[image: menu linking method]

So the final `<a href="/directory/#anchorlinktodesiredsection">menu item</a>` 
adds the path within it, this makes the soft sliding  not to work and although it moves to the place it does it by recharging the page.

What i would like is to find a method to be able to place only the #anchorlinktodesiredsection at the link so it glides again as in the original template.

`<a href="#anchorlinktodesiredsection">menu item</a><!-- no directory at href link-->`

i have tried to remove the directory by hand and it works. Obviusly this is not an answer for the system menu has to be able to add new sections without adding the path automaticaly

Any ideas ?

EDIT THANK TO wouho( posted the clue to solve this )

i edited my own mod_menu template and solved it.

```
if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) {
   /* $flink= JURI::base( true ).'/'.$flink;*/
$flink= $flink;
```

}

Comment: Did your template come with a demo with working menu items that act as anchors?

Comment: Yes , it did work before , i changed the language to spanish, but i dont see why this should add a path to the links if i set them to be #anchorlike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you don't have spaces before the # on the "Link" attribute of External URL. If that does not help would check for some strange template overwrites of mod_menu (templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/mod_menu).
Also are you using the joomla default mod_menu?

Comment: Yes it was that i had to remove from templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/mod_menu/default_url.php the line that said

   if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) {
          /* $flink= JURI::base( true ).'/'.$flink;*/
     $flink= $flink;
   }